# Run App Option not showing on the Pane, #R

Tags: r, shiny

I am learning about shiny dashboards, I am unable to find run app option which comes at the pane where we write our code the run app option is not visible. Kindly assist to enable the same.

Comment: which versions of software and RStudio are you using?

Comment: Dear Jimbou, my query got resolved, thank you so much for your time and support

Answer (score 7):

For Rstudio to display the run app button, it needs to recognize your script as a shiny app. One of the easiest way in Rstudio would be to go to file --> new file--> Shiny web app, since Rstudio would create the app.R file for you (by now you should see the run app button).

If you are working with a ui.R and server.R file, you should add the following line at the end of your server.R file:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You’re welcome, could you accept this as an answer?